# time_zone_options_for_select add default and priority

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, timezone

I have this piece of code, and I can't figure out how to set the selected option , or how to set the priority on the timezones

```
%select{id: "timezone", class: "select", name: "school[time_zone]"}
  = time_zone_options_for_select
```

time_zone_options_for_select returns a html string, i can't figure out how to work with that :-?

Any help is really aprecieated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer, http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_options_for_select.

As per this url, it will give you a string of options and you need to wrap that in a select tag.

```
time_zone_options_for_select('American Samoa')
```

to make "American Samoa" as the selected value. You can pass the required time zone name as first parameter to this helper method, to show that as selected value.

Comment: it works, but i don't know how to add the default selected timezone

Comment: Updated the answer to show the selected value, by passing the parameter to the helper method.